# how do I get spring to recognize the first capital letter using postgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a question how I can do so that in spring my table is recognized with the first capital letter, is made in postgresql

```
@Entity
@Table(name="System_user") 

public class Dashboard { 

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    String username;

get..
set...
}
```

it generates an error and I change it as shown below

```
@Table("\"System_user\"")
```

but he still doesn't recognize me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the issue was in dialect.
Latest dialect for now - `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect`

The issue solved this dialect:
`<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>`

---

Answer to your HQL-code:

I would suggest using TypedQuery as it returns not just a list, but list of your object.

Furthermore, u are using the same session to transfer data. This is bad for the program. Always do like `Open session - transfer data - close session`.

Try this code:

```java
public List<Vw_dh_assay> listAssayReport(double year, String project_id, String hole_id) {
        List<Vw_dh_assay> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Session session;

        try {
            session = this.sessionFactory.openSeesion();
            TypedQuery<Vw_dh_assay> query = session.createQuery("from Vw_dh_assay where year = :year AND project_id = :project_id  AND hole_id = :hole_id", Player.class);
            query.setParameter("year", year);
            query.setParameter("project_id", project_id);
            query.setParameter("hole_id", hole_id);

            list = query.getResultList();

            System.out.println(list);

            session.clear();
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code DAO @Antonio112009

```
@Override
    public List<Vw_dh_assay> listAssayReport(double year, String project_id, String hole_id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        String query = ("SELECT DISTINCT year,project_id,hole_id from "
                + "Vw_dh_assay where year = :year AND project_id = :project_id  AND hole_id = :hole_id");
        List result = session.createQuery(query).setParameter("year", year).setParameter("project_id", project_id)
                .setParameter("hole_id", hole_id).list();

        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Never add here code... This is only for answers) Only in your question u can do that...